# Openshift mysql cannot start MySQL

Tags: mysql, openshift, openshift-cartridge

I'm having issues in deploying the app on openshift. It was Working before but then when i pushed some updates Mysql suddenly became erratic. Below is the screenshot of the error.

[image]

```
R

emote: Preparing build for deployment
remote: Deployment id is 27960fb5
remote: Activating deployment
remote: Starting MySQL 5.5 cartridge
remote: MySQL server failed to start:
remote: 151109 05:19:51 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/lib/openshift/563c24947628e1f167000124/mysql//stdout.err'.
remote: 151109 05:19:51 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/openshift/563c24947628e1f167000124/mysql/data/
remote: 151109 05:19:51 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/openshift/563c24947628e1f167000124/mysql/data/
remote: 151109  5:19:51 [Note] /opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/libexec/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.45) starting as process 105921 ...
remote: 151109  5:19:51 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
remote: 151109  5:19:51 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
remote: 151109  5:19:51 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
remote: 151109  5:19:51 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
remote: 151109  5:19:51 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
remote: 151109  5:19:51  InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() failed with EAGAIN. Will make 5 attempts before giving up.
remote: InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() attempt 1 failed.
remote: InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() attempt 2 failed.
remote: InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() attempt 3 failed.
remote: InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() attempt 4 failed.
remote: InnoDB: Warning: io_setup() attempt 5 failed.
remote: 151109  5:19:54  InnoDB: Error: io_setup() failed with EAGAIN after 5 attempts.
remote: InnoDB: You can disable Linux Native AIO by setting innodb_use_native_aio = 0 in my.cnf
remote: 151109  5:19:54 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot initialize AIO sub-system
remote: 151109  5:19:54 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
remote: 151109  5:19:54 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
remote: 151109  5:19:54 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
remote: 151109  5:19:54 [ERROR] Aborting
remote: 151109  5:19:54 [Note] /opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete
remote: chown: changing ownership of `/var/lib/openshift/563c24947628e1f167000124/mysql//stdout.err': Operation not permitted
remote: 151109 05:19:54 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/openshift/563c24947628e1f167000124/mysql/pid/mysql.pid ended
remote: 151109 05:19:54 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/openshift/563c24947628e1f167000124/mysql/pid/mysql.pid ended
```

Comment: This may need investigating your gear. Could you please try sshing into your gear `rhc ssh adminconnect` and running `quota -s`; sending us the output with reference to this question at developers.openshift.com/contact? Thanks.

Comment: You might also try running the rhc app tidy command and see if that frees up enough space to get your gear working again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like that is a bug with OpenShift Online, try following the suggestion in this bug report (https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1085282) for a workaround.

```
1. Set the OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_AIO=0 for mysql cart
rhc env-set OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_AIO=0 -a <appname>

2. Restart the mysql-5.5
rhc cartridge restart mysql-5 -a <appname>

3. SSH into this app
rhc ssh <appname>
mysql

mysql> show variables where Variable_name = 'innodb_use_native_aio';
+-----------------------+-------+
| Variable_name         | Value |
+-----------------------+-------+
| innodb_use_native_aio | OFF   |
+-----------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try this next time it happens. I've fixed this issue by replacing MySQL Cartridge.